# Печать PNG в правильном разрешении стандартными средствами Windows 7

Tags: png, печать

Есть программа, генерирующая PNG файл в определенном разрешении, например 600ppi. Разрешение, соответственно стандарту PNG, указывается в chunk поле  "pHYs" в виде размера файла в миллиметрах. Проблема в том, что стандартный диалог печати Windows (как и редактора Paint) видимо игнорирует эти метаданные, и печатает изображения, то ли растягивая их на весь лист, то ли всегда с разрешением 96ppi. Если открыть и напечатать такой файл, например, из программы IrfanView, или редактора GIMP - масштабируется правильно. И Photoshop скорее всего тоже.
Но очень хотелось бы найти достаточно простое решение через стандартный диалог печати, так как рекомендовать пользователям специально для печати этих файлов устанавливать дополнительный софт - не вариант.
Прилагаю пример изображения и скрины, иллюстрирующие проблему.

[тестовое изображение в разрешении 600ppi, физический размер 84.71x71.42 мм](https://yadi.sk/d/wkwkM2mI3PaH3n)

[image: скрин 1]

[image: скрин 2]